# Rvest'ing using 'for' loops in R

Tags: r, for-loop, data-mining, rvest

My goal is to get the weather data from one of the websites. I *(with a little help of kind stack users, thank you)* already created  the vector consisting list of 1440 links and decided to try and use the 'for' loop to iterate over them.
Additionaly, every page has weather for each week so it's 7 rows of data (one for each day) which i have to obtain, which are marked as num0/num1/num2/num3.

That's what I came up with:

```
Links <- #here are the 1440 links i need to iterate over
library("rvest")
for (index in seq(from=1, to=length(Links), by=1)) {
  link = paste(Links[index])
  for (num in 0:7) {
  node_date <-paste(".num",num," .date",sep="")
  node_conditions<-paste(".num",num," .cond span",sep="") 
#here I tried to create an 'embeded for loop' to iterate 7 times over various nodes consisting data
  page = read_html(link)
  DayOfWeek = page %>% html_nodes(node_date) %>% html_text()
  Conditions = page %>% html_nodes(node_conditions) %>% html_text()

    
}
}
```

For now I get an error

> error in command 'open.connection(x, "rb")':HTTP error 502

and I'm really quite confused what should I do now.

Are there other ways to accomplish this goal? Or maybe I'm making some rookie mistakes in here?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: A 502 error is bad response from the server.  Please check your Links to ensure your urls are correct and valid.  Without more information there is little help to provide.

Comment: Thank you, I'll start from checking the links then